# Does Blender consider each frame to be separate scenes, while rendering animation?

Tags: animation, scene

While rendering an animation in blender is each frame considered a different scene?

I don't have much experience with animations what I do know is that while creating a video several images are rendered (frames) and then combined at about 24FPS.

My question is, are each of these frames considered a to be a different Scene?

Comment: I suspect that it is possible to access a specific property value for a given object and use that to set the value of another property via scripting. Yet, I do know that you can do this with drivers.

Comment: I would recommend asking question #2 as a new question.

Comment: @user3927312 answering the second part here would be unuseful regarding the the question title (for other users)

Comment: I'll create a new question for it. But I do believe it's related to the first question so I'll leave it in here as well. Would that be okay?

Comment: As this question stands, it's pretty unclear what you're asking. What do *you* consider to be a "scene"? I'm assuming that you're not familiar with Blender's concept of scenes (else you'd realize that they're quite distinct from frames), so you'll need to provide more information about what your question really is.

Comment: @user3927312 It's prefered that you only ask one question a time - unless question #2 requires context from question #1. In this case question #2 can stand on it's own, and therefore it should =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only answer the first question.

Each frame is NOT considered a different scene. Every scene has their own frames/timeline.

So "Scene 1" could have 250 frames, and "Scene 2" could have 150 frames. However, the first 150 frames in each of these scenes are different. Changing some animation in frame 50 in "Scene 1" does not affect frame 50 in "Scene 2" (unless you've specifically linked them).

At the top of Blender, you can see which scene you currently reside in:
[image]